# Spring Security Custom AuthenticationProvider Login post give 302 error

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have implement custom `AuthenticationProvider` spring login security. When i post it using its `/login` url it gives me *302* HTTP status code. whats the issue in that i have on custom filter for every request for handle every request

Filter

```
public class AppFilter implements Filter {

private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(AppFilter.class);
private CommonService commonService;

public AppFilter() {}

public void destroy() {}

public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    try {
        if (httpServletRequest.getRequestURI().contains("/resources/")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(httpServletRequest, servletResponse);
        }
        else {
            HttpSession session = httpServletRequest.getSession();
            if(session != null && session.getAttribute(CommonConstant.XXX) == null) {


                List<Map<String, Object>> clientDetails = commonService.getXXX(XX);
                if (clientDetails != null && !clientDetails.isEmpty()){

                    session.setAttribute(CommonConstant.CLIENT_SESSION_DATABEAN, clientSessionDataBean);
                }
            }

            HttpServletRequest request = new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(httpServletRequest);
            filterChain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(httpServletRequest.getRequestURI(), e);
        servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/common/unauthorized-access.jsp").forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
    }
}

public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
    ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(arg0.getServletContext());
    commonService = ctx.getBean(CommonService.class);
}

class CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private Map<String, String[]> allReqParam;

    public CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
        super(request);
        allReqParam = new TreeMap<String, String[]>();
        if(ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
            allReqParam = request.getParameterMap();
            List<FileItem> multipartItems = new ServletFileUpload(new DiskFileItemFactory()).parseRequest(request);

            for (FileItem multipartItem : multipartItems) {
                if (multipartItem.isFormField()) {
                    processFormField(multipartItem, allReqParam);
                } else {
                    processFileField(multipartItem, request);
                }
            }
        } else {
            Map<String, String[]> reqParamMap = super.getParameterMap();

             if(reqParamMap != null && !reqParamMap.isEmpty()) {
                 for(Entry<String, String[]> entry : reqParamMap.entrySet()) {
                     String paramName = entry.getKey();
                     String[] paramValue = entry.getValue();

                     identifyHiddenFields(paramName, paramValue);
                 }
             }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process multipart request item as regular form field. The name and value of each regular
     * form field will be added to the given parameterMap.
     * @param formField The form field to be processed.
     * @param parameterMap The parameterMap to be used for the HttpServletRequest.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    private void processFormField(FileItem formField, Map<String, String[]> parameterMap) throws Exception {
        String name = formField.getFieldName();
        String value = formField.getString();
        String[] values = null;

        if(parameterMap != null && !parameterMap.isEmpty()) {
            values = parameterMap.get(name);
        }

        if (values == null) {   
            identifyHiddenFields(name, new String[] {value});
        } else {
            int length = values.length;
            String[] newValues = new String[length + 1];
            System.arraycopy(values, 0, newValues, 0, length);
            newValues[length] = value;
            allReqParam.put(name, newValues);
            identifyHiddenFields(name, newValues);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Process multipart request item as file field. The name and FileItem object of each file field
     * will be added as attribute of the given HttpServletRequest. If a FileUploadException has
     * occurred when the file size has exceeded the maximum file size, then the FileUploadException
     * will be added as attribute value instead of the FileItem object.
     * @param fileField The file field to be processed.
     * @param request The involved HttpServletRequest.
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    private void processFileField(FileItem fileField, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        request.setAttribute(fileField.getFieldName(), fileField);
        allReqParam.put(fileField.getFieldName(), new String[] {fileField.toString()});
    }

    private void identifyHiddenFields(String paramName, String[] paramValue) throws Exception {
        if(paramName.startsWith("hidden")) {
             String[] tParamVal = new String[paramValue.length];

             for(int i=0; i < paramValue.length; i++) {
                 tParamVal[i] = AppCryptoUtil.decryptHV(paramValue[i]);
             }

             allReqParam.put(paramName.substring(6), tParamVal);
         } else {
             allReqParam.put(paramName, paramValue);
         }
    }

    @Override
    public String getParameter(final String name) {
        String[] strings = allReqParam.get(name);
        if (strings != null) {
            return strings[0];
        }
        return super.getParameter(name);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String[]> getParameterMap() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(allReqParam);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getParameterNames() {
        return Collections.enumeration(getParameterMap().keySet());
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getParameterValues(final String name) {
        return getParameterMap().get(name);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Did not understand the question. Can you elaborate the problem you are facing

Comment: issue is when i login its give me 302 status code and login is not working

Comment: Did you manage to solve?same problem

Comment: its solved.. @Phate